# FTP LIST and PASV commands not working in one program, but only on one server

Tags: ftp, total-commander, proftpd

So the weirdest thing is happening to me right now.

I just installed a new server (Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 LTS) and installed ProFTPD to transfer files with ease.

I normally use TotalCMD for my FTP needs, but it just doesn't work with this server on this machine.
It connects just fine, but the LIST and PASV commands just stall and nothing happens.

I have tried WinSCP on this machine and TotalCMD on other machines, which both works. AND it's not just because TotalCMD is not working because it is working fine when I connect to other FTP servers.

My machine is running Windows 10 Pro 64bit and TotlCMD is version 9.0a with extra DLLs to make FTPS work.

Does anyone have a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Show us logs files from WinSCP and TotalCMD.

Comment: Maybe your total commander uses different type of connection to FTP (like passive or active mode) insteed of your working connection.